# How to disable browser Autocomplete/Suggestions on web form input on Windows 10 mobile?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, windows-10-mobile

I'm using Windows 10 Mobile Edge browser.
I have added attributes below and that helps for Android and IOS devices
but on Windows Mobile I still have that problem.

```
autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"
```

[image]

Comment: maybe this is mobile keypad setting

Comment: Yes, But I want to turn off that programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this Link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(v=vs.85).aspx

AutoComplete property is discussed in above MSDN forum in details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have already seen that article. That don't help.

Comment: Redirected to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes